# Access Not Configured google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

when i access the google drive uri https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1obpi0bmSDILX1cIQcVRNi1lUkm2K5xBFztmRFiM?fields=lastModifyingUserName%2CmodifiedDate%2CownerNames%2CselfLink&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

i have both Drive SDK, Drive API to ON in my services https://code.google.com/apis/console

but still get a:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

where as if i run this through the https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it it works fine!

how do i return correctly the json?

```
{
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1obpi0bmSDILX1cIQcVRNi1lUkm2K5xBFztmRFiM",
 "modifiedDate": "2012-12-13T20:41:07.602Z",
 "ownerNames": [
  "Norman"
 ],
 "lastModifyingUserName": "Norman"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i was using an old api key, this now works!

Comment: Creating a new client id fixed my problem also. It was previously working but mysteriously stopped. My old client id was of the format {number}.apps.googleusercontent.com and the new one is of the format {number}-{gibberish}.apps.googleusercontent.com.